# Nginx is ignoring client_max_body_size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload, nginx, unicorn

For some reason, putting `client_max_body_size 16M;` in my nginx.conf file has no effect - I'm still getting an HTTP 413 error when I try to upload images to my webserver.  I've restarted Nginx after each change to the configuration file, and I've tried putting the `client_max_body_size` directive in the location {} block, in the server {} block, and in the http {} block. I've even tried all three at the same time.

In looking around for an answer to this, someone suggested looking for `client_max_body_size` lines in other configuration files, like proxy.conf, which I do not have.

My Nginx config is nothing special - simply upstreaming a connection to a bunch of Rainbows (Unicorns) running on port 8080.

I'm trying to upload a 4.5mb jpg file, running Nginx 1.0.5 on Ubuntu 11.10.  Any idea why this isn't working?

UPDATE:

Seems one (?) of the Rainbows workers is restarting every 30 seconds.  Here's the output from rainbows.stderr.log:

```
E, [2012-01-29T17:27:05.977487 #25218] ERROR -- : adding listener failed addr=0.0.0.0:8080 (in use)  
E, [2012-01-29T17:27:05.978011 #25218] ERROR -- : retrying in 0.5 seconds (4 tries left)  
E, [2012-01-29T17:27:06.478767 #25218] ERROR -- : adding listener failed addr=0.0.0.0:8080 (in use)  
E, [2012-01-29T17:27:06.478964 #25218] ERROR -- : retrying in 0.5 seconds (3 tries left)  
E, [2012-01-29T17:27:06.979509 #25218] ERROR -- : adding listener failed addr=0.0.0.0:8080 (in use)  
E, [2012-01-29T17:27:06.979650 #25218] ERROR -- : retrying in 0.5 seconds (2 tries left)
E, [2012-01-29T17:27:07.480190 #25218] ERROR -- : adding listener failed addr=0.0.0.0:8080 (in use)
E, [2012-01-29T17:27:07.480353 #25218] ERROR -- : retrying in 0.5 seconds (1 tries left)  
E, [2012-01-29T17:27:07.980809 #25218] ERROR -- : adding listener failed addr=0.0.0.0:8080 (in use)  
E, [2012-01-29T17:27:07.980987 #25218] ERROR -- : retrying in 0.5 seconds (0 tries left)  
E, [2012-01-29T17:27:08.481638 #25218] ERROR -- : adding listener failed addr=0.0.0.0:8080 (in use)  
/usr/local/forrager/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.1.1/lib/unicorn/socket_helper.rb:144:in `initialize': Address already in use - bind(2) (Errno::EADDRINUSE)  
from /usr/local/forrager/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.1.1/lib/unicorn/socket_helper.rb:144:in `new'  
from /usr/local/forrager/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.1.1/lib/unicorn/socket_helper.rb:144:in `bind_listen'  
from /usr/local/forrager/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.1.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:222:in `listen'  
from /usr/local/forrager/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.1.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:733:in `block in inherit_listeners!'  
from /usr/local/forrager/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.1.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:733:in `each'  
from /usr/local/forrager/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.1.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:733:in `inherit_listeners!'  
from /usr/local/forrager/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.1.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:121:in `start'
from /usr/local/forrager/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rainbows-4.3.1/bin/rainbows:122:in `<top (required)>'  
from /usr/local/forrager/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rainbows:19:in `load'  
from /usr/local/forrager/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rainbows:19:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally solved this problem with help from a coworker.  Turns out the problem was occurring because I had improperly configured Rainbows (Unicorn).  In addition to specifying the max body size in the Nginx config, I also should have specified it in my Rainbows config.  I had tried putting a call to `client_max_body_size` in my Rainbows config before, which didn't work.  As it turns out, the `client_max_body_size` call should be placed in a Rainbows! block like so:

```
Rainbows! do
  client_max_body_size(16 * 1024 * 1024) # 16 megs
end
```

Problem solved.  I can now upload 4 and 5mb files with no issues.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

The bit you said was nothing special, actually is. Make sure the Unicorn process can write to files in /tmp - anything over a certain size is written out to disk instead of being held in memory. So make sure it can make temporary files. See tmpio.rb in Unicorn for detail.

Also, make sure you have client_max_body_size under http {} and nowhere else.

Comment: Thanks for your response!  The permissions of /tmp are 777 world-writable and I changed the Nginx config to only have `client_max_body_size` under http {}.  Unfortunately, it's still not working.  Watching an `ls` of /tmp during the upload doesn't show anything new being created there.  How else can I check to make sure Unicorn can access /tmp?

Comment: check you can post to unicorn byitself. Take nginx out of the equation for a bit. Unicorn presents itself as HTTP so access it directly.

Comment: Hmm! Good suggestion. I'm seeing other very strange issues. When viewing the request/response in the Chrome developer tools (connected directly to the Unicorns), the request fails right away but doesn't actually give me an error code. The /add_image request turns red, however as though it failed. There are several other about:blank entries that show up, with only header information, and another which looks like a base-64 encoded PNG file (I'm uploading a jpg). Very strange. Are there any other Unicorn settings I'm missing? Sendfile or something like that?

Comment: Sounds to me that the back (the unicorns) is more of the issue than nginx is.

Comment: Indeed. Will continue to investigate.

Comment: After inspecting rainbows.stderr.log, it looks like one of the Rainbows workers is trying to restart every 30 seconds and can't bind to port 8080 because it's already in use (duh).

Comment: Ok, after a full 24 hours trying to debug this problem, I'm just going to switch to Thin, which actually works and gives meaningful error messages.  Screw you, Rainbows.